# Sankey diagram that looks like the one used by Google Analytics for users flow

Tags: highcharts, google-analytics-4, sankey-diagram

[GA4 users flow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77BDu.png)Is there a way to use your diagram to make something similar?

s                                                                 s

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to achieve the Sankey diagram in **Highcharts** by using the sankey module. Here is the official demo you can base on:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sankey-diagram

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey